# USB stick unmounts itself, becomes unavailable ?!

Tags: centos, mount, usb, copy

On Centos 6, I am trying to copy some files from a Fat32 stick.

I do a "fdisk -l" then take that name and mount it with this command:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb
```

I see the files there (I didnt count them tough), then I try to copy them from stick to HDD with this command:

```
cp -r 3 /_folder
```

Where "3" was the one and only directory on the stick, after it runs for a while I get these errors:

```
cp: reading `3/DEMO.AVI': Input/output error
cp: cannot stat `3/sample[1].flv': No such file or directory
cp: reading `3/sample2[1].flv': Input/output error
...
...
cp: cannot stat `3/file.mpeg': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `3/DivX.mpg': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `3/ddd.avi': No such file or directory
```

Files were copied partially on the destination.
Stick is not there anymore, is **like it unmounted itself**.
The stick is 8GB and I filled it with around 7.2GB.
File system is Fat32, I copied these files from Windows XP, I tried formatting the drive, same problem. And before this I had similar folders "1" and "2" copied OK. Maybe some file names can cause this?

Comment: Have you tried another stick ? It might be a faulty USB drive.

Comment: You may want to examine the output of `dmesg` at the time of failure. If you see your USB disk in `dmesg` being labeled as a "dead device", you may need a kernel upgrade, or the disk is just bunk.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I was able to copy after deleting some data.

Answer (score 0):

The copy completed properly after I deleted some data. I was eider out of space or some disk errors prevented me to write data. Webmin panel said I had some GB available and that is why I didn't thought of this before.